# Makefile with absolute paths and Git

Tags: git, makefile, project, development-environment, project-structure

I have a C project with custom Makefile. Its first line is the path to the project directory. So every machine, that works with this project, has to change this path to its working directory, and naturally this leads to new undesirable commit, especially if you push data. Moreover there are several external SDK which require paths too.

What are your solutions?

Comment: Why not modify your Makefile to use relative path to avoid changing according to working directory?

Comment: @gzh they are relative inside working dir. Also I have just found that make has  '§(CURDIR)' command. But what about external sdk that has to be connected to the project?

Comment: you can use [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) or [git-repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) to manage your sourcecode and external SDK in different repository and checkout them with directory layout you specified.

Comment: @gzh yes, I know this. The main reason which stops me is that someone turns out having it already and do not want to download it twice.

Comment: @gzh but this is actually one way I have in mind.

Comment: Then you have to resort to autotool to generate Makefile dynamically. For some simple application, you can write script to test the path you need and output the result to a file, then modify Makefile to reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditionally include an untracked makefile that sets the local paths (e.g. `-include config.mak`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can override variable which is assigned via simple `=` via command line:

```
$ cat Makefile
AAA = 1
all:
    echo $(AAA)
$ make
1
$ make AAA=2
2
```

Secondly, you can use `?=` and in that case Linux environment will also override Makefile's variable:

```
$ cat Makefile
AAA ?= 1
all:
    echo $(AAA)
$ export AAA=3
$ make
3
```

Then you can add variable to your `.bashrc` and forget about it.